# Common Build phases for a target

Tags: ios, xcode

Currently the way Xcode 9 ( and previous versions ) is set up, the Build phases for each target are unique. We have multiple targets and it is a pain to have to update say the Compile Sources build phase for each target separately. We would like each target to use a common build phase for Compile sources and for the 'Link libraries' build phase where if we add a framework to one target we need to update all targets. We coudn't see how to add these build phases to 'xcodebuild' input file. Anyone know how to do this.

Thanks